# CTRL + P not working on windows 7 laptop

Tags: ctrl

One of the users in the business has lost the ability to print in their windows 7 environment on their laptop when pressing CTRL + P.

Any ideas how I can resolve?

Comment: Which application you are using? Ensure Shift is not stuck. What is the laptop model?

Comment: Wont work in any application, tried word, adobe reader, outlook.... Keyboard seems fine as it does the same on usb keyboard and on the laptops actual keyboard. Its a Dell latitude e5430